# How to shuffle on images using output link and pass value to controller

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionfunction, outputlink

I have a requirement.

[image: Levels]

I have 4 images (or) icons on my VF page. I have a `NEXT` and `PREV` buttons.
So it is like, based on a `{!level}` value These images gets highlighted from step 1 .. step 4 based on the Level increment.

For the Highlighted images(orange color), 
For example, if the level is 3 currently, The user should be able to view Level 2 data and Level 1 data when they click on respective images.
Basically, if i shuffle across the levels and click it, i should get the desired list.

Here is what i have done so far, 
In my controller, My previous page and Next page goes by this,

```
public Integer level {get{return intLevel;} set;}

public PageReference PreviousPage()
    {
        saveSelectedOptions();
        intLevel--;
        getLstSSA();
        return null;
    }
public PageReference NextPage()
    {
            saveSelectedOptions();
            intLevel++;
            getLstSSA();
            return null;
        }
```

Here, in the above methods, the Next and prev operations runs on the same page with rerender of `GetLstSSA()`. 
`SaveSelectedoptions()` gives me the selected values on the pageblocktable. 
I need both these methods to render the list when i shuffle across levels

In MY VF page:

```
<apex:panelGrid id="NavPanel">

<apex:outputPanel id="level1" rendered="{! If(level == 1 ,true,false) }">
<div class="centerDiv">
    <div class="stepDiv completed"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel id="level2" rendered="{! If(level == 2 ,true,false) }">
<div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="stepDiv completed"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv completed"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- this goes till level 4 -->
```

Here, in the above code, '`stepDiv Completed`' denotes a `*Orange highlighted image*`. and '`stepDiv Incomplete`' denotes a `*Gray image*`. 
'`ellipsis`' are the dots in between.

How do i pass my `{!level}` value over each of this images and use `<outputlink>` or `<a href>` and retrieve the Level value and pass it to controller

Answer (score 0):

You just to add and handle the onclick event.

Page:

```
<div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="stepDiv completed" onclick="setPageLevel(1)"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv completed" onclick="setPageLevel(2)"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete" onclick="setPageLevel(3)"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv ellipsis"></div>
        <div class="stepDiv incomplete"></div>
</div>

<apex:actionFunction name="setPageLevel" action="{!setPageLevel}" rerender="NavPanel">
    <apex:param name="setLevel" assignTo="{!setLevel}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference setPageLevel()
{
    Integer setLevel = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters.get('setLevel');
    saveSelectedOptions();
    intLevel = setLevel;
    getLstSSA();
    return null;
}
```

Definitely you will need more code to handle your scenario to catch which step is already processed which is not. But the above code should be able to give you a brief idea.